# how to add date header to httpGet

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am currently using HttpGet(apache) method to make a request to a web service.
When I was calling the server it was giving me this error:

"The difference between the request time and the server time is too large"
Then I came to know that the server needs to have the request in GMT so I did add accordingly an header (addHeader) to do the same. But still I have the same issue.

Any thoughts/ideas?

some code:

```
    final String url = "ip address";
    final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValues = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "XXXX"));
    nameValues.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", "Fri, 19 Aug 2011 22:39:13 GMT"));
    for (final NameValuePair h : nameValues)
    {
        request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
    }
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    try
    {
        httpResponse = client.execute(request);
        responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        final HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        if (entity != null)
        {
            final InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            response = convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Can you use a "debugging proxy" like "webscarab" to verify headers and dump us a log of client-server interaction? https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_WebScarab_NG_Project

Comment: I have never done this...but using the link I will get the dump of the client-server interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it resolved.
I found out that the server has being set to GMT while I was calling with CST.